# Convert linear Array to 2D Matrix

Tags: c++, opencv

I got an float pointer (array), which represents an image.
It's elements count and index has width*height.
The image is not like a matrix, which has it's origin at the upper left.
Instead it has the origin in the lower left, like in the carthesian coordinate system.
After reaching the max-width, it starts it's next row at the left side.

So I want to efficiently convert this array to a 2D matrix (optional: opencv).

How do I do that in a good and effective manner?
And how do I convert it back?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is the purpose of this purely for addressing individual elements at locations (x,y) for lack of a better term? or is the intention to later pass this data to functions-unnamed that expect it to be in upper-left matrix layout. It makes a difference (one is math, the other is moving memory around).

Comment: the purpose is, that I want to work with opencv on that image data.
So I need the 'math' stuff.
After doing math and so on, I want to convert it back to the 'moving memory around' system, as you named it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll throw a rock in the lake and watch the ripples. Note: I have *no* idea what the caller expects to do with the xformed data, mostly due to my fledgling knowledge of OpenCV. However the core question of transformation seemed pretty straight forward. If I'm way off-base kindly leave a comment and I'll drop the answer. I propose two approaches, one for data inversion in-place, and one for simple accessor wrapping using a C++ class.

**In-place Inversion**: If the caller needs to invert the rows to accommodate usage for passing to an API, it can be done in place. Just be sure to do it again once you're done using the inverted data. An example purely byte-oriented is:

```
// in-place inversion of the linear matrix to re-origin.
void mat_invert(float *data, size_t height, size_t width)
{
    // must be at least 2 rows high for this to mean anything.
    if (height < 2)
        return;

    // setup a pair of pointers to walk the rows in byte-form
    unsigned char* top = (unsigned char*)data;
    unsigned char *bottom = (unsigned char *)(data + (height-1)*width);
    size_t row_width = sizeof(data[0]) * width;
    while (top < bottom)
    {
        for (size_t i=0; i<row_width; i++)
        {
            *top ^= *bottom;
            *bottom ^= *top;
            *top++ ^= *bottom++;
        }
        bottom -= 2*row_width;
    }
}
```

A sample usage:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const size_t w = 10;
    const size_t h = 5;

    float ar[h*w];
    memset(ar, 0, sizeof(ar));

    ar[0]       = 0.1;
    ar[1*w + 1] = 1.1;
    ar[2*w + 2] = 2.1;
    ar[3*w + 3] = 3.1;
    ar[4*w + 4] = 4.1;

    // dump original
    for (size_t i=0; i<h; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j=0; j<w; j++)
            cout << ar[i*w+j] << ' ';
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;

    // invert original
    mat_invert(ar, h, w);
    for (size_t i=0; i<h; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j=0; j<w; j++)
            cout << ar[i*w+j] << ' ';
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;

    // invert again
    mat_invert(ar, h, w);
    for (size_t i=0; i<h; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j=0; j<w; j++)
            cout << ar[i*w+j] << ' ';
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Results:

```
0.1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 1.1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 2.1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 3.1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 4.1 0 0 0 0 0 

0 0 0 0 4.1 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 3.1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 2.1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 1.1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0.1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 

0.1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 1.1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 2.1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 3.1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 4.1 0 0 0 0 0
```

---

**Implicit Access Class**: If all you need is virtualized row/height math done for you, the following will suffice to do just that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
#include <stdexcept>
using namespace std;

class matrix_xform
{
private:
    size_t width, height;
    float *data;

public:
    matrix_xform(float *data, size_t height, size_t width)
        : data(data), width(width), height(height)
    {
    }

    float * operator[](size_t x)
    {
        if (x > (height-1))
            throw std::out_of_range("matrix_xform[x]");
        return data + (width * (height - 1 - x));
    }

    const float * operator[](size_t x) const
    {
        if (x > (height-1))
            throw std::out_of_range("matrix_xform[x]");
        return data + (width * (height - 1 - x));
    }
};
```

A sample usage:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const size_t w = 10;
    const size_t h = 5;

    float ar[h*w];
    memset(ar, 0, sizeof(ar));

    matrix_xform mat(ar, h, w);
    mat[0][0] = 1.0;
    mat[1][1] = 1.0;
    mat[2][2] = 1.0;
    mat[3][3] = 1.0;
    mat[4][4] = 1.0;

    // dump original
    for (size_t i=0; i<h; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j=0; j<w; j++)
            cout << ar[i*w+j] << ' ';
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;

    // dump using accessor
    for (size_t i=0; i<h; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j=0; j<w; j++)
            cout << mat[i][j] << ' ';
        cout << endl;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Results:

```
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 

1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
```

I hope that covers every base the OP is looking for.

Comment: Your solution works great if the OP wants to use the matrix to access the transformed matrix in his own code, but he cannot pass your wrapper class object to an external API that might expect a 2-d float array as an argument.

Comment: Edited to add in-place inversion routine, `mat_invert()`. Hopefully that covers all the bases the OP needs.

Answer (score 1):

Planning your image processing API as

```
 void my_func (int *src, int *dst, int x_stride, int y_stride, int N);
```

makes it easy to iterate in continuous memory while flipping the scanning direction between left<->right, but also between up<->down.

If the API is designed for different input & output *strides*, one can also change the number of bytes per image element (change eg. color mode from RGBA to RGB or from 24-bit RGB to 16-bit R5G6B5, from int to float etc.) but also image width (and height also...).

The point is that math should be the same regardless of location of each row of the image.

One of these functions can be:

```
 copy_row(int *src, int* dst, int N, int x_stride);
 copy_2D_mem(int *src_base, int* dst_base, int N, int M, int y_stride, int x_stride);
```

Then again, it's quite possible that many of the existing opencv algorithms do not care about the orientation of the image. And writing one's own, the same approach could be utilized.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your problem, you want to pass your array to an OpenCV API so that it interprets it as a `(top,left)` indexed 2-d matrix. One simple way to do that without rearranging any of your array is illustrated by the following example :

```
float a[8] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};  //your array containing the image
int img_width = 2;
int img_height = 4;
float** b = new float*[img_height];
for(int i=img_height ; i>0; i--)
    b[img_height-i] = a+ (i-1)*img_width;

//call your API
do_something(b,img_height,img_width); 


//your OpenCV API that expects a 2-d matrix 
void do_something(float** x , int r, int c){};
```

If you want, you can turn this into a convenience function/macro that you can call to get the 2-d matrix in the desired format before calling the OpenCV API. Also, do not forget to de-allocate the memory for the temp array that was created for this purpose, once your are done.